# python's asyncio and sharing socket among worker processes

Tags: sockets, python-3.x, python-asyncio

Is it possible to share a socket amongst several worker processes using python's asyncio module?

Below is an example code that starts a server listening on port 2000. When a connection is established, and the client sends the string "S", the server starts sending data to the client. But all this happens only on one cpu core. How could I rewrite this example to take advantage of all the cpu cores? I took a look at asyncio subprocess module, but am not sure if I can use it to share the socket so that the server can simultaneously accept connections from multiple worker processes in parallel.

```
import asyncio
import datetime

clients = []

class MyServerProtocol(asyncio.Protocol):

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        self.transport = transport
        self.peername = transport.get_extra_info("peername")
        print("connection_made: {}".format(self.peername))
        clients.append(self)


    @asyncio.coroutine
    def send_data_stream(self):
        while True:
            yield from asyncio.sleep(3)
            if self in clients:
                self.transport.write("{} {}\r\n".format('Endless stream of information', str(datetime.datetime.now())).encode())
                print("sent data to: {}".format(self.peername))
            else:
                break 


    def data_received(self, data):
        print("data_received: {}".format(data.decode()))
        received = data.decode()
        if received == "S":
            asyncio.Task(self.send_data_stream())


    def connection_lost(self, ex):
        print("connection_lost: {}".format(self.peername))
        clients.remove(self)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    print("starting up..")

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    coro = loop.create_server(MyServerProtocol, port=2000)
    server = loop.run_until_complete(coro)

    for socket in server.sockets:
        print("serving on {}".format(socket.getsockname()))

    loop.run_forever()
```